# Maven -DlocalRepositoryPath not used, instead uses default local repository location

Tags: java, maven-2, repository, dependency-management

I'm using the following command to create a local repository within my project (used on many systems so I was experimenting a bit with having a local maven repository inside my project folder for storing external jars that can't be found on any online repository):

```
C:\Users\someone\workspace\someProject>mvn install:install-file
    -Dfile=somePackage-1.0.0.jar
    -DgroupId=foo.bar
    -DartifactId=somePackage
    -Dversion=1.0.0
    -Dpackaging=jar
    -DlocalRepositoryPath=libs
    -DcreateChecksum=true
```

This is run from Windows command line. Somehow, even with -DlocalRepositoryPath, it's still installing the jar into the default local repository (C:\Users\someone\.m2\, etc.). What am I doing wrong here? I tried different variations of the libs path, like /libs, /libs/, full path, using "", but nothing worked. Why isn't the -DlocalRepositoryPath argument not working here? I'm using Maven 2.2.1.

Comment: what's the error you get? Or does it build fine?

Answer (score 4):

The install:install-file option ignores the localRepositoryPath when using the version 2.2 of the plugin. However, it works with version 2.3 and higher.

Also, try using the fully qualified name of the plugin to specify the version:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file \
                         -Dfile=<path-to-your-file> -DgroupId=<myGroup> \ 
                         -DartifactId=<myArtifactId> -Dversion=<myVersion> \
                         -Dpackaging=<myPackaging> -DlocalRepositoryPath=<path>
```